# Objects with the same exact hash value in a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, hash, set

```
>>> class A():
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.x = "the set should have one element"
...     def __hash__(self):
...             return hash(self.x)
... 
>>> ob1 = A()
>>> ob2 = A()
>>> hash(ob1) == hash(ob2)
True
>>> {ob1, ob2}
{<__main__.A object at 0x7f6e2b39b5e0>, <__main__.A object at 0x7f6e2b3a8fd0>}
```

Can anyone explains this behavior? shouldn't the set have only one element?

Comment: Sets are based upon equality, not hash value.  The purpose of the hash is to speed up the implementation of sets, not to change their meaning.  You must also redefine __eq__.

Comment: @Frank: That's `__eq__`.

Comment: You've only guaranteed a hash-based *collision* because the objects hash to the same value. `A` inherits it's `__eq__` from `object`, which is jsut based on identity, so the two objects hash to the same value but are not equal

Comment: @martineau.  My bad for forgetting to put it inside backquotes.  I got bold instead of what I intended.  You are of course, correct.